# Bamboo build tying to undesired BitBucket Commit

Tags: bitbucket, bamboo, cicd

### Context

I have a BitBucket repo and a Bamboo Plan. The Bamboo Plan is tied to the Bitbucket repo in the "Repository" settings.
The Bamboo Plan "Branch" settings are set to create a new Branch when a new branch is created in the repo.

### Issue

When I create a branch, bamboo makes a new branch and starts the build. The first build is tied to the latest commit which came from the original branch. I don't want to associate the new branch build with a commit to the original branch. (It causes more than one build to be associated with the commit.)

### Desired Outcome

The build should only tie to new commits in the branch.

### Solutions

#### Pull Request Trigger

I modified my bamboo plan to only trigger new bamboo branches when a Pull Request is created for the repo branch. It did give me the desired outcome. The downside is that commits to the branch will not be executed against the CICD process until a PR is created.

Is there a way to create Bamboo branches only on the first commit to a new repo branch?

Answer (score 0):

No.

I'm sorry there isn't much you can do about this.